# set Java class Object values into JSP Page

Tags: java, jsp

I want to set Java class Object values into JSP Page.
My Test_Object code

```
public class Test_Object {
    public String email;
    public String first_name;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }
}
```

My test.jsp page

```
<%@page import="test.io.Test_Object"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="loginServlet" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name :
                <td><input type="text" value="" name="txtFirstname"
                    value='<%=((Test_Object) request.getAttribute("reqObj")).getFirst_name()%>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtEmail"
                    value='<%=request.getParameter("email")%>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My servlet code

```
String jb = "{\"email\":\"test@xyz.com\",\"fname\":\"test01\"}";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jb);
Test_Object obj = new Test_Object();
obj.email=jsonObject.getString("email");
obj.first_name=jsonObject.getString("fname");
request.setAttribute("reqObj", obj);
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp");
view.forward(request, response);
```

But when i redirect to test.jsp page there is no value display in TextBox.
I am using Eclipse Mars 2 with Java.

Comment: On which server are you deploying and why not using expression language?

Comment: @ujulu I am new in this. so please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be in the way you are dispatching the request. In your Servlet you are dispatching the request to the `/otn.jsp` page. But you are trying to read the properties of the object you put in the request scope in the `test.jsp` page.
So you have to do the following:

- In the Servlet code:

  ```
  RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp");
  ```
- In the `test.jsp` page change the `input` elements as follows:

  ```
  <input type="text" value="${reqObj.first_name}" name="txtFirstname"/>
  <input type="text" value="${reqObj.email}" name="txtEmail" />
  ```

I am using here Expression Language with the assumption that you are using one of the current web containers such as Tomcat version 7 and later.

Some minor comments:

1. Why are you creating the `JSONObject` eventhough you are not doing anything useful with it in your Servlet code?
2. When you define Java types (classes, interfaces, ...) use camelcase instead of underscore in the names: use `TestObject` instead of `Test_Object` and `firstName` instead of `first_name`. [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) you'll find naming conventions for Java.

Comment: Leave me a comment if you still experience a problem.